# extracting a list within a list in a tuple which happens to be in a pd.series

Tags: python, pandas, iterable-unpacking

```
x=     
[[(some text,[a]), (some text,[b]), (some text,[c]).........]]
   [[(some text,[d]), (some text,[e]), (some text,[f]).........]]
    [[(some text,[g]), (some text,[h]), (some text,[k]).........]]
    [[(some text,[i]), (some text,[x]), (some text,[y]).........]]
    [[(some text,[z]), (some text,[t]), (some text,[w]).........]]
    [[(some text,[t]), (some text,[g]), (some text,[u]).........]]

type(x)

pandas.core.series.Series
```

I want to create a series that only contains the values of the list within the tuple such as those`[a]` or `[u]` or `[w]`.

How can I extract? Thank you.

UPDATE: I realized the way I phrase the question was confusing. I changed it now. It represents my problem better. Basically, I need to extract all `[a]` or `[u]` or `[w]`row by row. This is tokenized text data, they are words in sentences. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Try `pd.Series([i for _, i in x])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given Series `s`,

```
s = pd.Series(x)
```

we can first get take the first elements out (since each row is a nested list), `explode` it and use the `str` accessor to get the second elements in each tuple; then take the elements out from singleton lists to get the raw data. Then `groupby` the index, and `join` the tokens.

```
out = s.str[0].explode().str[1].str[0].groupby(level=0).apply(','.join)
```

Output:

```
0    a,b,c
1    d,e,f
2    g,h,k
3    i,x,y
4    z,t,w
5    t,g,u
```

Comment: row1: ---> `[[(aaaa, ['bbbb']), (cccc, ['ddddd'])......]]'

Comment: row2: ---> `[[(eeee, ['ffff']), (gggg, ['hhhh'])......]]' so on. I need to get every list element within tuple for each row. think of as lemmatization form of a document. a cell contains many lemmatized word. These list within the tuples are the lematized form. Your code only gives one word for each cell.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had to groupby by index and apply a lambda, it worked. :)

Comment: thank you, my question was not clear enough. I updated the question. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: That is terrific. I cannot thank you enough. It worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
x =[('a',['b']), ('c',['d']),('e',['f'])]
x1 = pd.Series(x)
x1.apply(lambda y: y[1])
```

The result:

[image]

Based on your comment:

```
temp = pd.Series(["[[('aaaa', ['bbbb']), ('cccc', ['ddddd'])]]", "[[('a',['b']), ('c',['d']), ('e',['f'])]]"])
temp.apply(lambda x: [x[1] for x in eval(x)[0]])
```

And, the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I realized the variable is in another list too. I edited. Can you check it again? Sorry.

Comment: Check the answer now.

Comment: Thank you, my question was not clear enough. I updated the question. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

This Should Work:

```
old = [[('a', ['b']), ('c', ['d']), ('e', ['f'])]]


def main():
    for item in old:
        for sub_item in item:
            yield sub_item[1]


for x in main():
    print(x)
```

Comment: It was very close. :) little background: this is text data. each row contains this --> old = [[('a', ['b']), ('c', ['d']),('e', ['f'])]] your suggestion only gives one value from each row.

Comment: @OnerYigit Please check the edit which uses vanilla python

Comment: thank you, my question was not clear enough. I updated the question. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = pd.Series(x)

a=s.explode().explode().str[1].explode()

b=pd.DataFrame(a)

b.groupby(b.index)['column1'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)))
```

that code worked.